# How to auto scroll to an element that has no ID when loading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

If my element does not have an ID, but only class. Is it possible to auto scroll to the element that has no ID when loading the page?

Comment: yes it is possible, you just need to grab the element by class
var  targetElement =   document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0] , assuming your target element is the first element with test class.
then simply.
targetElement.scrollIntoView()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can. when you get elements by class in jquery you get an array of elements ... you can do it by bellow code:

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".elementtoScroll")[0].offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: you mean get elements by class in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jQuery code, providing with animation as well. Run the snippet and click the `button` to see it work.

You just have to focus on this part. Here `.box` is the element which is to be brought into view.

```js
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(".box").offset().top
}, "slow");
```

```js
$('button').click(() => {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".box").offset().top
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300vh;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```